# How to change the position of textarea resizing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple `textarea` like this:

```
<textarea name="txtarea" cols="14" rows="4"></textarea>
```

The shape and position of the above `textarea` is *bottom-right-corner*, like this:

[image: current shape]

Now I want to know how can I change it to this?

[image: what I want]

Comment: You need to simulate...place a div on the bottom of the texarea add a image and the play with jquery

Comment: do you mean I need to jquery for changing the size of that textarea?

Comment: Check this out - http://viralpatel.net/blogs/textarea-resize-javascript-jquery-plugin-resize-textarea-html/

Comment: @LuisP.A. seems good. tnx

Comment: @LuisP.A. Also you can write an answer according to what you referenced ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this simple `JQuery` tool to resize `textarea`.

Use code snippet

```js
var KeyDown;
$(".TxtArea > div").mousedown(function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass("Resize");
  $("body").addClass("UnSelectable");
  KeyDown = 1;
});
$(document).mouseup(function() {
  $(".TxtArea").removeClass("Resize");
  $("body").removeClass("UnSelectable");
  KeyDown = 0;
});
$(document).mousemove(function(Event) {
  if (KeyDown == 1 && $(".TxtArea").hasClass("Resize")) {
    var Height = Event.pageY - $(".TxtArea").children("textarea").offset().top;
    $("textarea").height(Height);
  }
});
```

```css
.TxtArea {
  width: 300px;
}
.TxtArea > textarea {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  resize: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.TxtArea > div {
  height: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0px;
}
.TxtArea > div:hover {
  cursor: n-resize;
}
.UnSelectable {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="TxtArea">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div>.....</div>
</div>
```

Or **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9kz3tna6/)**

Comment: May you please explain me why you have used `user-select` property?

Comment: I use it to prevent element select when textbox is resizing.