# Define position of resize button (corner)

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, resizable

**Scenario :**

- I have textarea that sits at the bottom of the page and is resizable, -
- but when the resize button sits at bottom-right corner then it is not the nicest experience for a user (just give it a try),

**Problem :**

- so I'd want to ask whether there is an possibility to move resize-button to e.g
  top-right corner?

http://jsfiddle.net/9bkgam2z/

```css
textarea
{  
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<textarea>
  test
</textarea>
```

Comment: remove ```position: absolute``` from css

Comment: @dorintufar He's asking about the resize corner of textarea

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33185480/how-to-change-the-position-of-textarea-resizing

Comment: This element is rendered by the browser itself and is not part of the HTML spec. Unless your designer is creating their own browser, you're stuck with the one you get.

Comment: see here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126917/can-i-style-the-resize-grabber-of-textarea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the position of textarea resizing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33185480/how-to-change-the-position-of-textarea-resizing)

Answer (score -1):

Here some CSS property value changes

```css
textarea
    { 
      position: initial;
      bottom: 10px;
      resize: vertical;
      overflow: auto;
      float: right;
    }
```

```html
    <textarea>
      test
    </textarea>
```

Comment: OP wants the resize button top right not the textarea